# javascript regex is giving error of illegal characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to use `match()` to look for a pattern.
Here is an example of the string i want to match: 12/03/2013 11:15

i used a few online tools and i got it working on those with this pattern:

```
sData.match((0[1-9]|[12][\d]|3[0-2])\/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/[\d]{4} (0[1-9]|1[\d]|2[0-3]):(0[1-9]|[1-5][\d])$)
```

However once i used it within my javascript code i get an error of illegal characters but ive not idea which characters are illegal can anyone help?

If it helps this is for a custom sort column for the datatables plugin but im sure this is not part of the problem.

Here is the online tool with the working regex: http://rubular.com/r/PR4l6T8AQi

Comment: You need to wrap the expression in `/` to create a regexp literal, `sData.match(/(0[1-9]...[\d])$/)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add the delimiters for the regex:

```
sData.match(/(0[1-9]|[12][\d]|3[0-2])\/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/[\d]{4} (0[1-9]|1[\d]|2[0-3]):(0[1-9]|[1-5][\d])$/);
            ^                                                                                            ^
```

That should work :)

Also, you can drop some of the character classes, such as `[\d]` can be written as `\d` all right:

```
sData.match(/(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[0-2])\/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/\d{4} (0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-3]):(0[1-9]|[1-5]\d)$/);
```

Comment: not to be pedantic but you have to deal with leap second: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second , nevertheless +1.

Comment: @M42 That's okay. OP's regex doesn't check for leap years either, I guess just as long as it follows the general format, it's fine. Thanks! ^^

Answer (score 2):

A literal regexp should start and end with /

Answer (score 0):

regex must start with / and end with /

```
 sData.match(/(0[1-9]|[12][\d]|3[0-2])\/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/[\d]{4} (0[1-9]|1[\d]|2[0-3]):(0[1-9]|[1-5][\d])$/)
```